# SQLPlus updating a text log file after procedure is executed

Tags: batch-file, stored-procedures, logfile

I have a batch (.bat) file with the below details that is automatically opened at 2 pm through the windows task scheduler.

Below are the contents of the Proc1.bat file:

```
@echo off
echo PROC 1 started at = %time% %date%>> C:\Users\username\Desktop\log.txt
sqlplus username/password@db @C:\Users\username\Desktop\procedure1.sql
```

below are the contents of the procedure1.sql file:

```
Exec schema1.procedure1;
prompt PROC1 Completed
```

Through the echo in the batch file I am able to update the log file with the start time
and through the prompt in the sql file i am able to tell that the procedure completed on the sqlplus screen
However, I need a way to update the end time "after" the procedure completes into the same log.txt file.

I do not have access to edit the stored procedure, i can only call it.
I have only read access to the Oracle schema and tables, i cannot make any changes procedure or other changes.
Please help me out with a way to update the log.txt file with "Proc1 executed successfully at hh:mm", "after" the procedure is completed.

I have spent hours and hours online trying to find a suitable result, but an unable to find any. Finally turning to the stack overflow experts for resolution!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to get the result:

I changed the contents of the SQL file to:

```
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET FEED OFF
EXEC schema1.procedure1;
SPOOL C:\Users\username\Desktop\log.txt APPEND
SELECT 'PROC 1 COMPLETED AT:', TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF') FROM DUAL
SPOOL OFF;
EXIT;
```

This appends a new line into the log.txt file that says:

```
PROC 1 COMPLETED AT: 08/30/2023 13:35:59.480663
```

So, the .BAT file adds the procedure start time into the log file and the .SQL file adds the procedure completed 'end time' into the log file.

This helps in creating a 'log file' that captures the start time and end time for all the scripts/batch files that are scheduled to run, which helps in identifying whether the procedures are executed on a daily basis or not.

FYI, I have assigned the scripts to run as tasks through the task scheduler application in Windows.